# PHP | LARAVEL | EloquentDataTable datatable query always returning 10 rows to the max

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to show the list of productOrders based on an order ID within one of my view. Here's the code snip from my app/Datatables/ProductOrderDatatables.php which i use to pull the list from my database table called "product_order" :

```
public function dataTable($query)
{
        $dataTable = new EloquentDataTable($query);           
        $columns = array_column($this->getColumns(), 'data');
        $dataTable = $dataTable
            ->editColumn('price', function ($productOrder) {
                return getPriceColumn($productOrder);
            })
            ->rawColumns(array_merge($columns));
        
        return $dataTable;   
}
```

Here's my query function within the ProductOrderDatatables.php :

```
public function query(ProductOrder $model)
{
              
       return $model->newQuery()->with("product")
        ->where('product_orders.order_id', $this->id)
        ->select('product_orders.*')->orderBy('product_orders.id', 'desc');
}
```

**Problem :**

-> Consider, I try to pull an order with order_id = 314
-> Here's how the entries look like within the database :
[image]
-> I get **ALWAYS** 10 results to the **MAXIMUM**. As you could see there are **11** entries , but i always get capped at 10. I don't understand where i should be looking for limit for `new EloquentDataTable($query)` if at all there's one.

Does somebody have an idea about what i should be looking ?? Running a raw SQL query within the datatabase SQL section returns all 11 as expected. Any hints/suggestions/solutions please ??

**Packages list**

- namespace App\DataTables;
- use App\Models\CustomField;
- use App\Models\ProductOrder;
- use App\Models\Product;
- use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;
- use Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable;
- use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;
- use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
- use DB;

Comment: Are you using any package for your datatables? If so, which one? Nothing in their documentation? Sounds like a pagination "problem"

Comment: @kerbh0lz : Sorry that i missed it. I'm using Yajra.. just updated the question with the list. Would you mind sharing the location of the file i should be looking into ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the rest of your entries by updating your code to the following code and read more on [paginate method laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results)

```html
public function query(ProductOrder $model)
{
              
       return $model->newQuery()->with("product")
        ->where('product_orders.order_id', $this->id)
        ->select('product_orders.*')->orderBy('product_orders.id', 'desc')->paginate(11);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fayza. Though this did't solve the issue, I disabled pagination from : yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/DataTableAbstract.php & it solved the problem for me. Thank you very much for your input